# How to use leftouter join in entity framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

[image]How to use leftouter join in entity framework query

I have two table one is item and other is stock available I want to get all items and also get its quantity from stock available table which depend upon the particular department

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example
LINQ Query

```
var query = (from p in dc.GetTable<Person>()
join pa in dc.GetTable<PersonAddress>() on p.Id equals pa.PersonId into tempAddresses
from addresses in tempAddresses.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { p.FirstName, p.LastName, addresses.State });
```

SQL Translation

```
SELECT [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[LastName], [t1].[State] AS [State]
 FROM [dbo].[Person] AS [t0]
 LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[PersonAddress] AS [t1] ON [t0].[Id] = [t1].[PersonID]
```

Comment: please tell me the query in linq to entitity this is in linq to sql

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500103/converting-a-left-outer-join-to-entity-framework